# Pandas DataFrame.groupby.nth inconsistent behavior. bug?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Let's define DataFrame a as follows and print it

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[10,1,5],[20,2,6],[10,3,7]],columns=['a','b','c'])
print(a)
```

which gives

```
    a  b  c
0  10  1  5
1  20  2  6
2  10  3  7
```

The output of

```
print(a[['b']].groupby(a.a, as_index=True).first())
```

is

```
    b
a    
10  1
20  2
```

The output of

```
print(a[['b']].groupby(a.a, as_index=True).nth(0))
```

is

```
   b
0  1
1  2
```

Therefore `as_index=True` is ignored which is inconsistent with previous command (using `.first()`). Now the output of

```
print(a[['a','b']].groupby(a.a, as_index=True).nth(0))
```

is

```
    a  b
a        
10  10  1
20  20  2
```

which is again inconsistent.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. Mine is consistent. What `pandas` version are you using? On my current machine I'm using '0.19.0'

Comment: Are you sure you haven't done something crazy, like alias `True` with `False`? That would only be possible on Python 2, anyways...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, haven't done anything crazy.

Comment: I didn't think you would. I only ask because I encountered that exact bug recently, where someone used `True` as a variable name and then the expression evaluated to False, causing all sorts of havoc.

Comment: Before you update, what is the result of `df.groupby('a', as_index=True)['b'].nth(0)`

Comment: Also, this might be relevant? : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5755

Comment: I updated to '0.19.0' and it fixed the problem. Thanks. I saw your message for trying `df.groupby('a', as_index=True)['b'].nth(0)` after update.